# Is it possible to write a udev rule to keep other udev rules from running?

Tags: linux, udev, rules

This

```
 http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html
```

says

```
 It is important to understand that udev will not stop processing when it finds a matching rule, it will continue searching and attempt to apply every rule that it knows about.
```

But I want to write a rule for a very specific device that keeps other rules including the default rules from running. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

At the very bottom of the doc 
http://www.novell.com/documentation/opensuse110/opensuse110_reference/data/sec_udev_rules.html

I found this:

OPTIONS
There are several possible values to the OPTION key:

last_rule tells udev to ignore all later rules.

Seems to work.